# List a file with only one occurrence of a word

Tags: regular-expression

I have a directory with a lot of files. Current files have this format `Application.log`, older logs are renamed in this fashion - `Application.log.06-05-2020.log`. I need to list only the files that have log only once in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.log' ! -name '*.log.*'
```

To find the files whose name ends in `.log` but otherwise does not contain `.log.`

As a `zsh -o extendedglob` glob:

```
print -rC1 - (^*.log.*).log
```

or (as a closer equivalent to the `find` one above):

```
print -rC1 - *.log~*.log.*
```

Or as a `ksh` or `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob` glob:

```
printf '%s\n' !(*.log.*).log
```

(set the `dotglob` option to also include hidden ones).

Comment: That worked, thak you @Stephane Chazelas. Is there a way to do it with the simple ```ls``` command, similar to ```ls /var/log/*.log```

Comment: @Haris, you could use `ls`, as in `ls -d -- the-glob` but using `ls` is pointless here unless you use options like `-s`/`-l` to retrieve more information as the listing (and sorting) job is actually performed by the shell filename generation (globbing) here so using builtin printing commands such as `print` or `printf` is enough and more efficient. In any case, if you want to use that list to do anything, you want neither `ls` nor `print`/`printf` but either use `-exec` with `find` or loop over the glob (`for file in theglob`) in the glob approaches.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Chazelas